# Clicking in one spot, registering as a click somewhere else

Tags: javascript, html-lists

So I am using the expandable lists as presented [here](http://jasalguero.com/ledld/development/web/expandable-list/) (with a demo [here](http://jasalguero.com/demos/expandableList/)), and so far the JavaScript code allows for a list to be expanded when the line immediately preceding it is clicked. I would like for the list (just one, not all) to expand when a line (or rather word, say `<mystyle>word</mystyle>`) somewhere else, not in the same line, not even in the same `div` is clicked.

Is this possible with JavaScript, or some CSS manipulation? I'm no expert, but I would really like to get this resolved.

Edit 1: Here is a small working example of the body of what I have. The loaded JavaScript is exactly as in the "Update" section of the linked website, as well as `jquery-1.4.2.min.js`.

```
<div style="width:350px">
<div id="listContainer"><ul id="expList">
<p align='center'>2011-06-28 - <a href="podcast.mp3"> Download</a> - <mystyle>Show/hide songs</mystyle>
<audio controls>
  <source src="podcast.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support this audio format.
</audio>
<li>List of songs<ul>
        <li>Song 1</li>
        <li>Song 2</li>
        <li>Song 3</li>
        <li>Song 4</li>
        <li>Song 5</li>
        <li>Song 6</li>
</ul></li></p>
</ul></div></div>
```

Basically I want to to be able to click `<mystyle>Show/hide songs</mystyle>` and the click to register on `<li>List of songs`.

Comment: please post the HTML and Javascript that you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('mystyle').click(function() {
  var mystyle = this;
  $('li:contains(' + $(this)[0].firstChild.data + ')').filter(function() {
    return $(this)[0].firstChild.data === $(mystyle).text();
  }).trigger('click');
});
```

This would attach a click function to the `mystyle` element, take the text inside the `mystyle` element and filter the `li`'s based on the text inside of them. Then trigger their `click` event. You'd have to ensure unique texts inside the `li`'s to avoid unpredictable behaviour. It would be better to use `id`'s instead. In theory you wouldn't need the `:contains()` bit, but it might speed things up a little as it ensures the filter is iterating a smaller collection.

**Edit**

The above solution would work if the text inside `<mystyle>` is the same as the text inside the `li` which you want to trigger the `click` event on. Since this is not true in your case, it would be better to assign some `id`'s and work with them instead, it requires less code and DOM iterations.

**Relevant HTML extract from your example**

```
<mystyle id="showhidesongs">Show/hide songs</mystyle>

<li id="listofsongs">List of songs
  <ul>
    <li>Song 1</li>
    <li>Song 2</li>
    <li>Song 3</li>
    <li>Song 4</li>
    <li>Song 5</li>
    <li>Song 6</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#showhidesongs').click(function() {
  $('#listofsongs').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Ok, I think I see where this is going, but I'm having some trouble. I added your code verbatim inside `function prepareList() {`, and added the word `this` to the line I want to be clicked, but nothing happens when I click the text inside `<mystyle>` (see the example I put in the question). Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I have edited the answer with an example of how to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can build this by rewriting the code on the page you linked. Below is the existing code:

```
function prepareList() {
  $('#expList').find('li:has(ul)')
    .click( function(event) {
      if (this == event.target) {
          $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
          $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
      }
      return false;
    })
   .addClass('collapsed')
   .children('ul').hide();
};

$(document).ready( function() {
  prepareList()
});
```

When you read this you'll see that the child `ul` of the `li` that is clicked is hidden or shown. If you want to change that, you'll have to rewrite this logic using something like `id`'s. You can add a `data-target="abc"` to the `li`, have the jQuery code read that value and open or close the `ul` that has that value as its `id`. You'd have to make sure that all parents are also opened or else you'll see nothing happening of course